# How to fix Can't find bundle for base name ncs_rest_sim, locale en_us when running devspace simulator on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, java, error-handling, locale

I Am trying to install devspace simulator on ubuntu 20.10 with java version "1.8.0_271" and I get the following error when I run it:

**HTTP ERROR 500**

Problem accessing /. Reason:

```
Can't find bundle for base name ncs_rest_sim, locale en_us
```

**Caused by:**

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name ncs_rest_sim, locale en_us
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1581)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1396)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:854)
    at hms.kite.simulator.webui.StaticPropertiesService.init(StaticPropertiesService.java:56)
    at hms.kite.simulator.webui.MchoiceSdpSdkServlet.init(MchoiceSdpSdkServlet.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:970)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:1054)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:529)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```